# How to initialize an array of pointers to functions with a loop

Tags: c, function-pointers

Is there a way to obtain all the adresses of func1 to func4 so that I could use them inside a for loop to initialize my menu ? I have a feeling this could be possible with some sort of macro trickery. I've looked through google and SO but I didn't find any help.

```
...
void func1(void) { printf("func1\n"); }
void func2(void) { printf("func2\n"); }
void func3(void) { printf("func3\n"); }
void func4(void) { printf("func4\n"); }

int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {
    int num=0;
    printf("Scanf: 0 - 4\n");
    scanf(" %d", &num);

    void (*menu[])(void) = {func1,
                            func2,
                            func3,
                            func4};

    if(num <= 4) (*menu[num-1])();
...
```

Comment: Where is the problem ? Your code looks more or less fine.

Comment: Declare a function pointer type *with a parameter*. Make array of this function pointer type. Iterate the array and pass the iteration-specific parameter (e.g. string with number). Profit. BTW, why not just use a *single* function with different parameters?

Comment: @MichaelWalz - There is no problem, I was curious if for some reason I had a 100 functions like that if then I'd be able to initialize my menu array using a loop instead of manually writing each functions name

Comment: @ShadyProgrammer OK; now I understand. The answer is NO. If you have 100 different functions, it's not a big deal to put all of them in an array. BTW how would you determine the order of the functions in the menu and which functino to put there ? The answer below maybe what you want, but this only works if the functions have names like `funcX` where X varies from 1 to N and you still need to do one bug #define containing all `EXEC(x)`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I can't wrap my head around your suggestion, could you post an answer to demonstrate please ?

Comment: @MichaelWalz Let's say I wanted to put all functions that come before main in order from top to bottom and each had a different name but all return void and take void, still no ?

Comment: @ShadyProgrammer No, the C language doesn't offer such a thing. Your qustion is really a non issue. Putting the function addresses in an a array is not a big deal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to obtain all the adresses of func1 to func4

No, the addresses of such functions could be in non contiguous areas

> I have a feeling this could be possible with some sort of macro
>   trickery.

Are you looking for a way to declare and assign at once?

In this case:

```
#define PROTO(name) static void func##name(void) { printf("func"#name"\n"); }
#define EVENT(name) func##name,

#define EVENTS(EXEC) \
    EXEC(1) \
    EXEC(2) \
    EXEC(3) \
    EXEC(4)

EVENTS(PROTO)

int main(void)
{
    void (*menu[])(void) = {EVENTS(EVENT)};

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
static void func1(void) { printf("func""1""\n"); }
static void func2(void) { printf("func""2""\n"); }
static void func3(void) { printf("func""3""\n"); }
static void func4(void) { printf("func""4""\n"); }

int main(void)
{
    void (*menu[])(void) = {func1, func2, func3, func4,};

    return 0;
}
```